# Добавление иконки в input

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Есть разметка:

```
<div class="level-2">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Откуда" class="from">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Куда" class="where">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Вес (кг)" class="weight">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Объём (м3)" class="size">
  <a href="#" class="button blue-btn">Рассчитать стоимость</a>
</div>
```

Её стиль:

```
.main .online-services .cost .level-2 > input {
    flex: 1 1 0;
    border-radius: 0px;
    margin-left: -0.5px;
}
```

Задача внутрь input добавить иконку, сейчас пробую сделать реализацию так:

```
.main .online-services .cost .level-2 input::before {
    background: url(../image/icons/svg/024-pin.svg);
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    content: '-';
  }
```

К сожалению не работает, просьба помочь.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Картинка в поле input](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/894636/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5-input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
input {
  background: url(https://uncovery.me/websend/user_icons/36a93bf5-af50-433e-b887-963923bcf3a8.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 100% 0;
  height: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Откуда" class="from">
```

Вариант два с `hover`  и картинкой в формате SVG и еще решил привести пример, когда `input` а фокусе

```css
input {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,\
          <svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" \
           viewbox="0 0 21 21" width="21" height="21" >\
          <style>svg{background: #000;}\
          <\/style> <path fill="red"  d="M11 0 21 21 0 21z"></path></svg>');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 100% 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  padding-right: 120px;
  transition: background .5s;
}

input:hover {
  background-color: green;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,\
          <svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" \
           viewbox="0 0 21 21" width="21" height="21" >\
          <style>svg{background: #fff;}\
          <\/style> <path fill="red"  d="M0 0 21 0 11 21z"></path></svg>');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 100% 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  padding-right: 120px;
}

input:focus {
  background-color: blue;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,\
          <svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" \
           viewbox="0 0 21 21" width="21" height="21" >\
          <style>svg{background: #fff;}\
          <\/style> <circle fill="deepPink" stroke="green" stroke-width="2" cx="11" cy="11" r="5"></circle></svg>');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 100% 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  padding-right: 120px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: Саму логику Ваш вариант решает, но как в рамках этой логики по отдельности поменять цвет иконки и бекграунда?
Например при :hover нужен будет серый фон и синяя иконка.

Comment: Так меняйте отдельно `background-color` и `background-image`